# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: binary-search-tree

I'm currently working on a problem regarding Binary Search Trees. My problem is that I get the error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'" and I don't see what I can do about it. This code is in my BST class.

```
 def _insert(self, data):
    if self.root.value == data:
        return False
```

I have a Node class and a BinarySearchTree class.

```
class _Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.right_child = None
        self.left_child = None
        self.value = value

class BST:
   def __init__(self):
       self.root = None
```

I imagine it has something to do with the fact that self.root is set to None in my **init**() function. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`self.root` is `None` so when you check `self.root.value`, the root has no such element.

Instead of initializing `self.root=None`, initialize `self.root=Node(None)`

Also while inserting, if you are planning to insert to `root`, then check if the `root.value` is `None`, if yes, insert else the rest of your logic

Comment: Okay, I see! My problem, however, seems to remain since the next line

elif self.root.value > data:
     if self.root.left_child:  
          return self.root.left_child._insert(data)

returns this error message

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: Great, I think that solved the error message! Altough, now I receive AssertionError that None =! X as I try to count the inserted values X. But I'll look over the code again and see if I can solve it. Thanks

Comment: Ok cool, if I was of any help, please upvote or accept my answer, Happy learning!!!